# In JJ Thompson's experiment, why are electrons not making U turns?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, charge, capacitance, scattering

In JJ Thompson's experiment,

1. Why are some electrons able to pass through the slit of the anode, rather than hitting the anode plate itself?
2. Even though electrons manage to get past the anode, will it decelerate, as the anode keeps attracting it from behind now? So electrons make a U turn.

Comment: Don't forget the entire set of electrodes, and note that it is a *change* of potential that gives an electric field and hence a force.